# How to play video of mp4 Format in Java Swing using RTSP

Tags: java, swing, video, rtsp

I am using JAVA SWING to implement a video application which can handle MP4 and MJPEG video formats.
I can play MJPEG video format but can't play MP4 videos.
Do you have some advice that what changes i need to make in this code, so that MP4 videos can also be handled.[video player in JAVA using RTSP](http://www.csee.umbc.edu/~pmundur/courses/CMSC691C/lab5-kurose-ross.html)

Answer (score 1):

VLCJ and OpenCV both offer out of the box connection to RTSP streams. They can be displayed in JPanels live. OpenCV is easier but way overkill for image processing and VLCJ simply just creates a VLC player instance in a panel.

This question is old but I recently ran into the same problem and hope people find this helpful.